# I have a problem that I cannot set the buttons with conditions in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random
            
def click(buttons):
    global click
    global player_score
    global cpu_score
    global win
    global btn_list
    global turn
    click = random.choice(btn_list)
    while turn < 10 and not win:
        if buttons['text'] == ' ' and click == False :
            buttons.configure(text='O',fg='yellow')
            buttons.configure(state=DISABLED)
            click = True
        else:
            buttons = random.choice(btn_list)
            buttons.configure(text='X',fg='green')
            buttons.configure(state=DISABLED)
            click = False
    
    if (btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn3['text'] == 'O' or
        btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' or
        btn7['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
        btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
        btn3['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
        btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
        btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' or
        btn3['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O'):
            player_score += 1
            win = True
    elif (btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn2['text'] == 'X' and btn3['text'] == 'X' or
        btn4['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn6['text'] == 'X' or
        btn7['text'] == 'X' and btn8['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X' or
        btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X' or
        btn3['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn7['text'] == 'X' or
        btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn4['text'] == 'X' and btn7['text'] == 'X' or
        btn2['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn8['text'] == 'X' or
        btn3['text'] == 'X' and btn6['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X'):
            cpu_score += 1
            win = True



window = Tk()
window.title('Tic Tac Toe')


buttons = StringVar()

btn1 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn1))
btn1.grid(row=1,column=0)

btn2 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn2))
btn2.grid(row=1,column=1)

btn3 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn3))
btn3.grid(row=1,column=2)

btn4 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn4))
btn4.grid(row=2,column=0)

btn5 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn5))
btn5.grid(row=2,column=1)

btn6 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn6))
btn6.grid(row=2,column=2)

btn7 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn7))
btn7.grid(row=3,column=0)

btn8 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn8))
btn8.grid(row=3,column=1)

btn9 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='red',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn9))
btn9.grid(row=3,column=2)

btn_list = [btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9]

player_score = 0
cpu_score = 0
turn = 1
click = False
win = False
```

---

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/Python/Python Projects Fun/tic-tac-toe_gui.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    btn8 = Button(window,text=' ',bg='blue',height=4,width=8,command=lambda:click(btn8))
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

When I run and click any one of the buttons then the error message came out. I would like to set one player as computer that will click on the random button then change players' turn so may I ask how can I write in order to have this effect? Also I would like to ask when should we use lambda in functions?

Comment: You have redefined `click` in the end of your code `click = False`.

Comment: So I delete this line and anymore to change?

Comment: Not sure what did you want to do.But if you remove this line, the button could be pressed without exception but the tkinter application is freezed.

Comment: Actually my aim is to take turns between me and cpu but I don't know how to set the cpu to pick random button choice so any possible solutions without freeze?

Comment: You used `while` loop in your function, it won't end so that's why your app would be freezed.

Comment: So should be ```turn += 1``` to continue?

Comment: You also need to remove the `click = xxx` in the function `click`.

Comment: Then how to change player turns?

Answer (score 1):

You need a partial. A partial is part lambda. I have tried to read about lambda, but none of it quite stuck. The way I think about it is lambda is live. If I need to pass a variable to a call back I use lambda to declare I need a living(changing variable). In this situation you need a live function, but a static variable for each button, so you need a partial. In the below code where all the global variables in your click function change with the program every time you press btn1 it will send the click function a zero, btn2 a one, and so on. I went ahead and corrected your callback functionality and a robot function that calls itself using the .after method. The 1000 is time in milliseconds, so you can adjust accordingly.

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import random


def click(button_num):
    global player_score
    global cpu_score
    global win
    global btn_list
    global turn
    global player
    button = btn_list[button_num]

    if button['text'] == ' ':
        button.configure(text='O', fg='yellow')
        button.configure(state=DISABLED)
        player = not player


def robot():
    global window
    global player_score
    global cpu_score
    global win
    global player
    if not player:
        button = random.choice(btn_list)
        if button['text'] == " ":
            button.configure(text='X', fg='green')
            button.configure(state=DISABLED)
            player = not player

    if (btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn3['text'] == 'O' or
            btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' or
            btn7['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
            btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
            btn3['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
            btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
            btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' or
            btn3['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O'):
        player_score += 1
        win = True
    elif (btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn2['text'] == 'X' and btn3['text'] == 'X' or
          btn4['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn6['text'] == 'X' or
          btn7['text'] == 'X' and btn8['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X' or
          btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X' or
          btn3['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn7['text'] == 'X' or
          btn1['text'] == 'X' and btn4['text'] == 'X' and btn7['text'] == 'X' or
          btn2['text'] == 'X' and btn5['text'] == 'X' and btn8['text'] == 'X' or
          btn3['text'] == 'X' and btn6['text'] == 'X' and btn9['text'] == 'X'):
        cpu_score += 1
        win = True
    window.after(1000, robot)


window = Tk()
window.title('Tic Tac Toe')

buttons = StringVar()

btn1 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='red', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 0))
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn2 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='blue', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 1))
btn2.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn3 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='red', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 2))
btn3.grid(row=1, column=2)

btn4 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='blue', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 3))
btn4.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn5 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='red', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 4))
btn5.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn6 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='blue', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 5))
btn6.grid(row=2, column=2)

btn7 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='red', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 6))
btn7.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn8 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='blue', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 7))
btn8.grid(row=3, column=1)

btn9 = Button(window, text=' ', bg='red', height=4, width=8, command=partial(click, 8))
btn9.grid(row=3, column=2)

btn_list = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9]

player = True
player_score = 0
cpu_score = 0
turn = 1
click = False
win = False

robot()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: but why it does not stop if one player gets three boxes matched together?

Comment: I did not address that issue; I wanted to leave some fun for you. You could check the win variable as well in the if statements. If you want the robot function to stop running entirely you would have to write an if statement for it. If you made a new game button / function; you could use it to clear your buttons, reinitialize your variables, and start the robot function again. I'm happy to help, but I'm not going write the whole thing.

Comment: so I need to make one more define with if statement inside?

Comment: You can make it stop by changing ```if button['text'] == " ":``` to  ```if button['text'] == " " and not win:``` in both functions.

Comment: Successful now Thanks